# Unexpected result (first pass disappeared) when doing two-pass Gaussian blur in OpenGL(C++)

Tags: c++, opengl, gaussianblur

I'm trying to implement a background-blur effect with OpenGL.

Here is my thought:

1. drawing all background element to `colorFBO`
2. draw `colorFBO` into pingpongFBO[0] and pingpongFBO[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKvcc.png)
3. use pingpongFBO[0] as texture, draw hori-blur rect to pingpongFBO[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKvcc.png)
4. use pingpongFBO[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKvcc.png) as texture, draw vert-blur rect to  pingpongFBO[0]

Here is the result with blur radius of 200:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKvcc.png)

[image]

As you can see, the hori-blur effect disappeared almost.

The **edge of blue rectangle** is still sharp.

If I only draw hori-blur part, it looks correct, the edge is now blurry.

[Hori Only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM6zC.png)

[image]

Here is my blur frag shader code

```c
#version 330 core
#define pow2(x)(x*x)
#define PI 3.14159265
uniform sampler2D screenTexture;
uniform bool horizontal;
uniform float radius;

out vec4 FragColor;
float gaussian(float x){
    float sigma2=2.*pow2(radius/3.);
    return(1./(sqrt(PI*sigma2)))*exp(-pow2(x)/sigma2);
}
void main(){
    vec2 resolution=vec2(600,600);
    vec2 uv=vec2(gl_FragCoord.xy/resolution);
    vec4 color=vec4(0.);
    float weight=gaussian(0);
    color+=texture2D(screenTexture,uv)*weight;
    float accum=weight;
    if(horizontal){
        for(int i=1;i<radius+1;i++){
            vec2 off=vec2(i,0)/resolution;
            weight=gaussian(i);
            color+=texture2D(screenTexture,uv+off)*weight;

            color+=texture2D(screenTexture,uv-off)*weight;
            accum+=weight*2;
        }
    }else{
        for(int i=1;i<radius+1;i++){
            vec2 off=vec2(0,i)/resolution;
            weight=gaussian(i);
            color+=texture2D(screenTexture,uv+off)*weight;

            color+=texture2D(screenTexture,uv-off)*weight;
            accum+=weight*2;
        }
    }
    FragColor=vec4((color/accum).xyz,1.);
}
```

Here is main CPP :

```cpp
#include "Common.hh"

const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 600;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;
float left = 150;
float top = 200;
float radius = 200;
void processInput(GLFWwindow *window);
int main()
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    float *quad1Vertices = rectWithSize(SCR_WIDTH, 200);
    float *quad2Vertices = rectWithSize(200, SCR_WIDTH);
    float *blurQuadVertices = rectWithSize(200.0, 200.0);
    float backgroundVertices[] = {
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};

    unsigned int quad1VAO, quad1VBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &quad1VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &quad1VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(quad1VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad1VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, RECT_SIZE, quad1Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);

    unsigned int quad2VAO, quad2VBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &quad2VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &quad2VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(quad2VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad2VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, RECT_SIZE, quad2Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);

    unsigned int quad3VAO, quad3VBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &quad3VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &quad3VBO);
    glBindVertexArray(quad3VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quad3VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, RECT_SIZE, blurQuadVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);

    unsigned int backgroundVAO, backgroundVBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &backgroundVAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &backgroundVBO);
    glBindVertexArray(backgroundVAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, backgroundVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(backgroundVertices), &backgroundVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4 * sizeof(float), (void *)(2 * sizeof(float)));

    Shader shader("simple_rect.vs", "simple_rect.fs");
    Shader screenShader("screen.vs", "screen.fs");
    Shader blurShader("blur_rect.vs", "blur_rect.fs");
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, (float)SCR_WIDTH, 0.0f, (float)SCR_HEIGHT, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0);
    shader.use();
    shader.setMat4("projection", projection);

    blurShader.use();
    blurShader.setMat4("projection", projection);
    blurShader.setInt("screenTexture", 0);

    screenShader.use();
    screenShader.setMat4("projection", glm::mat4(1.0));
    screenShader.setMat4("model", glm::mat4(1.0));
    screenShader.setInt("screenTexture", 0);

    GLuint colorFBO;
    GLuint colorBuffer;

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &colorFBO);
    glGenTextures(1, &colorBuffer);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, colorFBO);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer, 0);

    GLuint pingPongFBO[2];
    GLuint pingPongColorBuffer[2];
    glGenFramebuffers(2, pingPongFBO);
    glGenTextures(2, pingPongColorBuffer);
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, pingPongFBO[i]);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pingPongColorBuffer[i]);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, pingPongColorBuffer[i], 0);
    }

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        processInput(window);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, colorFBO);
        glClearColor(229.0 / 255.0, 229.0 / 255.0, 229.0 / 255.0, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        shader.use();
        shader.setMat4("model", glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 100.0f, 0.0f)));
        shader.setVec4("uColor", glm::vec4(0.3451, 0.7333, 0.2, 1.0));
        glBindVertexArray(quad1VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        shader.setVec4("uColor", glm::vec4(0, 178.0 / 255.0, 1, 1.0));
        shader.setMat4("model", glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(50.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)));
        glBindVertexArray(quad2VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, pingPongFBO[0]);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        screenShader.use();
        glBindVertexArray(backgroundVAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, pingPongFBO[1]);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBuffer);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        screenShader.use();
        glBindVertexArray(backgroundVAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, pingPongFBO[1]);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pingPongColorBuffer[0]);
        blurShader.use();
        blurShader.setMat4("model", glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(left, top, 0)));
        blurShader.setInt("screenTexture", 0);
        blurShader.setBool("horizontal", true);
        blurShader.setFloat("radius", radius);
        glBindVertexArray(quad3VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, pingPongFBO[0]);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pingPongColorBuffer[1]);
        blurShader.setBool("horizontal", false);
        glBindVertexArray(quad3VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        screenShader.use();
        glBindVertexArray(backgroundVAO);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, pingPongColorBuffer[0]);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &quad1VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &quad1VBO);

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &quad2VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &quad2VBO);

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &quad3VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &quad3VBO);

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &backgroundVAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &backgroundVBO);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

The full source code is [here](https://github.com/xVanTuring/opengl-blur-test)

Comment: *"the hori-blur effect disappeared almost"* - but it is there. Of course the green color is dominant. What is the question? Change the blue color to red color and compare the result.

Comment: But vertical edge should be blurry right? Like the second image with  hori-blur effect only, the right edge of blur rect is blurry.

Comment: The vertical edge is blurry. But the effect is reduced and covered by the vertical blur in the 2nd pass. Note, the vertical blur reinforced the vertical edge, because it blurs along this edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertical edge is blurry. But the effect is reduced and covered by the vertical blur in the 2nd pass. Note, the vertical blur reinforced the vertical edge, because it blurs along this edge.
After the 1st pass (horizontal blur), the main color on the left side is still blue and the main color on the right side is still green and white. The vertical blur, mix the colors along the columns of the image. That causes that the transition along the columns between the left (blue) and right (green/white) becomes a noticeable edge.

[image]

If you change the order of the passed (1st vertical blur, 2nd horizontal blur), then the horizontal edge becomes visible again:

[image]

In general the algorithm works. Compare the result, when a diagonal blur is used:

[image]

```c
void main(){
    // [...]

    if(horizontal){
        for(int i=1;i<radius+1;i++){
            vec2 off=vec2(i,i)/resolution;

            // [...]
        }
    }else{
        for(int i=1;i<radius+1;i++){
            vec2 off=vec2(-i,i)/resolution;

            // [...]
        }
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Comment: You are right! I think I should use the area where only the blur rect covers as texture and blur it. That should provide the result I want. Thanks!